# Store error message in a variable in native PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to store error messages(Fields are empty or incorrect credentials) in a variable and just echo it in a  `<div>`tag?

Comment: yea.. you can do that.. Just push error messages in an array one by one.. and display into div using loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
$message = "Hello";
```

And

```
<?php if (!empty( $message)) {?>
    <div><?php echo $message;?></div>
<?php }?>
```

if you are setting the messages on other pages then use `session`. Like -

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Hello";
```

And

```
<?php if (!empty( $_SESSION['message'])) {?>
    <div><?php echo $_SESSION['message'];?></div>
<?php }?>
```

And dont forget to add `session_start()` at the start of the page.

Comment: is it ok to declare error_reporting since it displays undefined variable message before i submit the form?